# mkdir -p dir with braces created wrongly

Tags: bash, directory, brace-expansion, mkdir

I executed the following code in Ubuntu server 16.04 xenial:

```
mkdir -p /root/backups/{db, dirs}
```

I recall that in another system, it worked like charm creating all 3 dirs:

```
/root/backups/
/root/backups/db
/root backup/dirs
```

Yet this time the result was:

```
/root/backups/
/root/backups/{db,
```

Why is this partial, broken result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bash, like any POSIX shell, [splits commands into tokens](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01) before [expanding words](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) (which, in Bash, [includes brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)).

```
mkdir -p /root/backups/{db, dirs}
```

contains a space, so the command is first split into the tokens `mkdir`, `-p`, `/root/backups/{db,`, and `dirs}`. None of these need further expansion, so `mkdir` is run with the three arguments `-p`, `/root/backups/{db`, and `dirs}`. It creates `{db` in `/root/backups`, and `dirs}` in the current directory.

If you drop the space you’ll get the behaviour you’re after.

Comment: No way to bypass that "spaceophobia" right there?

Comment: No, because you might actually _want_ those three oddly named directories for some reason.

Comment: With the space escaped or quoted, it would create `/root/backups/db` and `/root/backups/␣dirs`, with the space. Which probably isn't what you want.